# OnNewIntent is not called after PackageInstaller failure

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-install-apk

I use this code for installing APK: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61889386/14152249

My activity launch mode is set to SingleTop. I call InstallPackageAndroidQAndAbove from OnActivityResult (I need to uninstall app before that and I check if it's uninstalled there). Also I modified that code to pass the `PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent` flag during the creation of `PendingIntent` object. The problem is when APK is successfully installed or when installer is waiting for user action, OnNewIntent is always properly called and then I do some stuff. But when user aborts install, OnNewIntent is not called (occasionally though it DOES get called). I couldn't find anything about such a behavior. How can I fix this? Or maybe it has something to do with the device which I'm debugging on (Xiaomi Mi 9T Pro with MIUI 12 based on Android 10)?

I need to show an alert dialog when app failed to install and stop the process. As a workaround I use StartActivityForResult and then in OnActivityResult I wait for 5 seconds and check if app is installed. But this workaround is bad of course because if installation takes more than 5 seconds then alert dialog will be shown anyway though the app itself will be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a lot better workaround than the one described in my question. It's still a workaround though as I couldn't find an explanation of such strange behavior.

The only thing I need from this is actually notifying about installation fail. I declared a class which inherits `PackageInstaller.SessionCallback`. It looks like this:

```
public class PackageInstallObserver : PackageInstaller.SessionCallback
{
    private PackageInstaller PackageInstaller { get; }
    public event EventHandler InstallFailed;

    public PackageInstallObserver(PackageInstaller packageInstaller) => PackageInstaller = packageInstaller;

    public override void OnActiveChanged(int sessionId, bool active) { }

    public override void OnBadgingChanged(int sessionId) { }

    public override void OnCreated(int sessionId) { }

    public override void OnFinished(int sessionId, bool success)
    {
        PackageInstaller.UnregisterSessionCallback(this);
        PackageInstaller.Dispose();
        if (!success) InstallFailed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public override void OnProgressChanged(int sessionId, float progress) { }
}
```

Then in my `InstallPackageAndroidQAndAbove` method I create an instance of that class and pass it to `packageInstaller.RegisterSessionCallback` method. So now `InstallPackageAndroidQAndAbove` looks like this:

```
public void InstallPackageAndroidQAndAbove(Android.Net.Uri apkUri)
{
   var packageInstaller = PackageManager.PackageInstaller;
   var sessionParams = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstallMode.FullInstall);
   int sessionId = packageInstaller.CreateSession(sessionParams);
   var session = packageInstaller.OpenSession(sessionId);

   AddApkToInstallSession(apkUri, session);
        
   // Create an install status receiver.
   var intent = new Intent(this, this.Class);
   intent.SetAction(PACKAGE_INSTALLED_ACTION);
   var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
   var statusReceiver = pendingIntent.IntentSender;

   // Create an observer and register it
   var observer = new PackageInstallObserver(packageInstaller);
   observer.InstallFailed += OnInstallFailed; // Subscribe to event
   packageInstaller.RegisterSessionCallback(observer);

   // Commit the session (this will start the installation workflow).
   session.Commit(statusReceiver);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445004/11104068), in order to ensure that your `OnNewIntent` is called, you have to pass this flag:  `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, during the creation of the `PendingIntent` object. So if you're following the example you shared, this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(activity, 0, intent, 0);
```

Should be this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(activity, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to mention in my question that I actually pass this flag. I'll edit my question to include this information.