# Opening browser on notification click is not working on MI phones

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-notifications

In Xiaomi phones, when I try to redirect to a browser on the click of a notification using the following code :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            try {
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
```

Redirect is not working and it is throwing an error that "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?".

I am

It is working fine in other phones. Can anyone help in solving this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you call startActivity out the the activity class. use below code for your problem it will work. for reference you can see

> [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK clarification needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772927/flag-activity-new-task-clarification-needed)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
 intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            try {
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: But it is working in other phones. That flag is needed only in MI phones.

Comment: not just for MI phone it happens on other phones too i faced this issue on  samsung galaxy s5. you can add above code and it will work for every device.

Comment: But what if I want to a particular activity in my app using a deep link?