# Why is FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK needed for opening the home screen programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio

I found this code snippet to programmatically go to the home screen on clicking the back button.

```
  public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(a);
    }
```

What is the purpose of using `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` ?

Comment: Exactly what the documentation says https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FLAG\_ACTIVITY\_NEW\_TASK clarification needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772927/flag-activity-new-task-clarification-needed)

Comment: I understand what the use of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is. I just can't seem to comprehend why it is needed here.