# Duplicate activities on the back stack after initial installation of APK

Tags: android, android-intent, android-lifecycle, android-install-apk

This is somewhat difficult to explain (or phrase as a question), but I can provide plenty of examples.  This issue occurs with many of the popular applications that are available on the Google Play Market.

I am also able to reproduce it using Google's own IoSched 2012 application.

Example:
1) Install IoSched from the Play Store https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.iosched&hl=en

2) At the end of the installation, USE THE OPEN BUTTON (*this is important) to immediately open the application.  Do not take any actions in the application.

3) Press the HOME key on your device.

4) Find the application in your Apps list and re-launch it using the launcher.

5) Press the HOME key again, repeat 3 and 4 several times.

6) Finally, re-launch the application for the final time using the launcher.

7) Press the back button.  Instead of returning to the home screen, the device will display the duplicate copies of the initial activity from the back stack.  There will be as many copies of the same activity as the number of times you repeated steps 3 and 4.

8) I have been able to reproduce this using my own application, IoSched2012, CraigsList, eBay, and ConnectBot applications.

9) The Google Earth application works correctly.

10) If you do not use the OPEN button to initially open the application, but rather use the launcher from the Home screen, the application will function correctly.

Does anyone have any ideas on resolving this issue?

Comment: Sounds like a bug the android team should know about: http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html

Comment: I recall that there is an issue filed for this one out on http://b.android.com, but I cannot seem to locate it at the moment.

Comment: Based on your responses, I was able to find this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26658&q=install%20open%20done&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: That bug report links to a possible workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341600/how-to-prevent-multiple-instances-of-an-activity-when-it-is-launched-with-differ/

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue that I was thinking of.

Comment: The work around given here solved my problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341600/how-to-prevent-multiple-instances-of-an-activity-when-it-is-launched-with-differ/