# Application process is cloned after HOME button is pressed

Tags: android

Actions to reproduce bug:

1. Install APK (doesn't matter from [market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.aviascanner.aviascanner) or eclipse or via usb connection) (
2. Do some stuff i.e. set cities, start search.
3. Press HOME button.
4. Open application launcher menu.
5. Press Aviascanner icon.
6. In some cases (about 5%) system starts new clean copy of application without selected cities and other data. If you press BACK button you can see previous copy of app (so it works in one task).

This behavior can be watched on this devices:

1. Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 OS 4.0.4
2. Samsung Gt-s6500d OS 2.3.6

I can't reproduce it in HTC Wildfire S A510e.

Also you can look at the [youtube video](http://youtu.be/pJ844ZmXc6Q) where bug is reproduced (sorry for bad quality and russian language but the bug is very uncommonly, it was very hard to catch it)

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: You should read more carefully. Look at the step 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Step #2 is triggered by clicking "Open" from the post-install screen, or by running the app from Eclipse, this is [a long-standing issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26658) with Android.

This question outlines some options: [How to prevent multiple instances of an activity when it is launched with different intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341600/how-to-prevent-multiple-instances-of-an-activity-when-it-is-launched-with-differ/)