# Application always restart from MainActivity

Tags: android, xamarin

I made my own application, everything works fine when I debug my application from debugger, but when I create the package for release or when I upload the app on Google Store, something goes wrong.

When I launch the application from the home launcher, my app restarts from MainActivity but when I launch the app from desktop, everything works fine. It seems like there is an android bug, I can't figure it out. It happens only when I put my app on the Store.

The steps are:

1. Install application from the store.
2. Open the application.
3. Put the application on background.

If I reopen the application from the Launcher ( Home ) the application restart from MainActivity ( the app is no destroyed! ), if I reopen the application from the Desktop, everything works fine and the application open the last activity that I opened.

Can anyone help me?

**[Update 1]**

This bug is present if i create a package and i install the application with AirDroid, everything works fine is i deploy the app directly from Xamarin. This is insane.

**[ Update 2 ]**

**I Tried to create a new project with just two activity, MainActivity and TestActivity. MainActivity launches TestActivity when a button is pressed, if I put the app on background and resume it with launcher, this always restart the app from mainActivity with OnCreate Method called!**

This is only when I create a package, when I work on debugging, everything works fine.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Are you put android:launchMode="singleTop" in your activity declaration into manifest file?

Comment: This is a known bug. Check this out 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341600/how-to-prevent-multiple-instances-of-an-activity-when-it-is-launched-with-differ

Comment: No, i'm using a Empty Project now.. And this problem is still present.

Comment: Thanks redsnowfox i will try to read that link!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a known bug, you can find all solution here: [How to prevent multiple instances of an activity when it is launched with different intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341600/how-to-prevent-multiple-instances-of-an-activity-when-it-is-launched-with-differ)

Thanks a lot to everyone for the answers!