# Pending intents for multiple intents opening wrong activities

Tags: android, android-widget, android-pendingintent

I have two widgets A and B. I have two issues:

1. On tapping a widget (A or B) multiple times, multiple instances of
   the same activity opens up.
2. Sometimes Widget A opens widget Bs activity and vice versa.

Here is my code:

Widget A Provider class:

```
 for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.favorite_flavor_widget);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
        intent.setAction("FromFavoriteFlavorWidget");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        intent.putExtra("FromFavoriteFlavorWidget", true);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.favoriteFlavorBox, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
    }
```

Widget B Provider class:

```
 for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.report_food_widget);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
            intent.setAction("FromReportFoodWidget");
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("FromReportFoodWidget", true);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.reportFoodBox, pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
        }
```

Comment: setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); try this

Comment: not working.  Multiple instances of the activity are tting created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

settings flags as   `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`

and try adding this to manifest.

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

and

```
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent );
```

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

Comment: Actually it works when the app is completely closed but if the app is in background it does not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341600/how-to-prevent-multiple-instances-of-an-activity-when-it-is-launched-with-differ

Comment: Just tell me  when you are pressing back from activity. navigation issue ? right then you supposed to use TaskStackBuilder along with PendingIntent  please go through http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/notify-user/navigation.html

Comment: The issue now is that if the app is in the background and I tap on the widget, it does not open the correct fragment, it just opens the app and shows the existing fragment.

Comment: why dont you pass a boolean variable from widget via intent and when the boolean variable is true on activity , then replace the current fragment with required fragment.

Comment: I am doing that.      if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(Constants.PUSH_NOTIFICATION_EXTRA, false) || getIntent().getBooleanExtra("FromLiveFeedWidget", false)) {
                onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(5));
            } else if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("FromFavoriteFlavorWidget", false)) {
                onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3));
            }
        }

Comment: I found the solution. Just had to put those checks in onNewIntent call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104059/discussion-between-sree-reddy-menon-and-rohit-ramkumar).

Answer (score 0):

Why are u calling

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
```

2 times call it only one time and use `android:launchMode="singleTop"`for multi instance issue