# Prevent Android from recreating already existent activity

Tags: android, android-activity, deep-linking, recreate, deeplink

My problem is with deeplinking to my app. To be more specific, this also only happens when trying to open a deeplink to my app from Facebook Messenger with chat heads active.

Sometimes, when trying to return(not open, just return after messenger has overlayed app) to my app(which has only one activity) using a deeplink from FBMessenger the activity gets recreated. `onCreate` method is called and a new instance of my activity is being created. The main problem is that this does not happen after the old activity is destroyed, I've added logs and first new activity's `onCreate` gets called, and only after that old activity's `onDestroy` gets called.

So why does Android try to create a new instance of my activity if it hasn't destroyed the old one yet?

Activity's `launchMode` is set to `singleTask`.

Edit: Also tried with `launchMode` set to `singleInstance` or `singleTop`.

Edit 2: Found possible fix by adding `android:documentLaunchMode="intoExisting"` to activity. Will do a few more tests tomorrow morning and post this fix as solution if everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your Android manifest

```
 android:documentLaunchMode="intoExisting"
```

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html for more info

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast answer but it doesn't work. Same behaviour. I'll update my question.

Comment: I did, but couldn't find any setting that might prevent this behaviour.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341600/how-to-prevent-multiple-instances-of-an-activity-when-it-is-launched-with-differ/

Comment: Something like that might work, will try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: That didn't work, it crashes the app. Also, one other interesting fact is that my activity's onNewIntent never gets called.

Comment: It's default Branch.io sdk implementation. I just managed to find a possible fix by adding android:documentLaunchMode="intoExisting" to activity. It seems to work, but I still want to do a few tests tomorrow morning and if it turns out to be the solution I'll let you know. Thank you very much for your time and sugestions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149728/discussion-between-ekundayo-blessing-funminiyi-and-boby).